# Trouble getting delegate working in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm just starting to learn Objective-C and I'm not 100% on all the syntax yet, and I think that might be where I'm having trouble, then again I'm not sure. I'm trying to get one view controller to send a message to its parent/callee view controller. I have it set up like this:

```
//ParentViewController.h

#import "SubViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController <SubViewControllerDelegate>

- (void) sendMessageToParent:(NSInteger)num;

@end
```

This is the implementation:

```
//ParentViewController.m

@implementation ParentViewController

- (void) sendMessageToParent:(NSInteger)num
{
    NSLog(@"Message is %d", num);
}

- (void) buttonPushed
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubView" sender:sender];
}

@end
```

Here's the other view controller setup:

```
//SubViewController.h

@protocol SubViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void) sendMessageToParent:(NSInteger)num;

@end

@interface SubViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <SubViewController> delegate;

@end
```

And implementation:

```
//SubViewController.m

@implementation SubViewController

@synthesize delegate;

- (void) something
{
    [self.delegate sendMessageToParent:4];
    [self.dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: It doesn't work. The log doesn't log.

Comment: Did you ever assign the `delegate` property to a `ParentViewController`?

Comment: FYI - the words "doesn't work" are the most useless words a developer can use. Whenever you report an issue, you must be clear and specific about what the problem is. If there are build issues, specify them and where. If the app crashes, indicate the complete and exact error message and point out the line causing the crash. If it runs but doesn't do what you expect, explain exactly what it should do and what it isn't doing. Explain what debugging has been done to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Okay there was no crash... It built, it runs, it just doesn't delegate the message to the delegate, as suggested by the title 'trouble getting delegate working'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add to ParentViewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SubView"])
    {
        SubViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        vc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add handler for `prepareForSegue` and set `.delegate` properly there. I don't think your SubviewController has delegate set to the parent one.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're not setting SubViewController's delegate to SuperViewController. You'd do this typically when you instantiate SubViewController. e.g. `subViewController.delegate = self`

ParentViewController.h

```
@interface ParentViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

ParentViewController.m

```
@implementation ParentViewController <SubViewControllerDelegate> // Better to place this in .m than .h

#pragma mark - SubViewController Delegate

- (void)sendMessageToParent:(NSInteger)num
{
    NSLog(@"Message is %d", num);
}

- (void)buttonPushed
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"SubView" sender:sender];
}

@end
```

SubViewController.h

```
@protocol SubViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)sendMessageToParent:(NSInteger)num;

@end

@interface SubViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<SubViewController> delegate;

@end
```

SubViewController.m

```
@implementation SubViewController

// @synthesize delegate; // Not necessary, old fashioned

- (void)something
{
    // Set a breakpoint here and step through, you're not setting your delegate, so this conditional is not being hit
    if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(sendMessageToParent:)])
    {
        [self.delegate sendMessageToParent:4];         
    }

    [self.dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: Is your delegate nil in the `something` method?

Comment: Yes it is coming up nil